# Memory Expansion For Asus Eeepad Transformer

Tags: internal-storage, ram, asus-eee-pad-transformer

Hello I am planning on getting the 16GB version of the Eeepad Transformer, however I would want to upgrade the memory via the expansion slot.Does anyone have an idea up to how many gigs the expansion slot supports ?

Comment: Just FYI, when you say memory, most people assume you mean RAM - not storage.

Answer (score 3):

When you say memory do you mean storage capacity? As far as im aware there is no way to increase the 1GB memory it is supplied with.

**EDIT :**

This site states 32GB expansion limit for SD card, which seems like its porbably correct :

http://www.techwench.com/asus-eee-pad-transformer-review/

Comment: Yes sorry I meant storage capacity

Comment: meaning i can put in an extra 32gb sd card, sweet

Answer (score 1):

Limit of the internal reader is that of SDHC format: 32Gb.

But AFAIK, card slots on the Transformer dock is SDXC compliant, so, limit is 2Tb (theoretical)

Comment: SDHC goes well beyond 2GB, up to 32GB. Asus's specs for the TF also don't note SDXC support anywhere.

Comment: Oops... the "3" lost in the keyboard buffer!

Answer (score 1):

The SDHC (high-capacity) card family have a capacity of 4 GB to 32 GB
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital
https://www.sdcard.org/developers/tech/sdhc/